# How to spy on an AsyncFunction with jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

`handler.js`

```
const wait = require("./wait");

module.exports.hello = async (event) => {
  return await wait(event);
};
```

`wait.js`

```
const wait = async function (event) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: "Thanks for waiting!",
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };
};

module.exports = wait
```

`__tests__/handler.test.js`

```
const handler = require("../handler");
const wait = require("../wait");

describe("handler", () => {
  it("should call wait", async () => {
    const waitSpy = jest.spyOn(wait, "wait");
    await main.handler();
    expect(waitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm struggling to *spy* the async wait function. What am I missing please?

https://github.com/kaihendry/asyncfunction-spy

Comment: are you getting errors? or is the test failing?

Comment: Error is: Cannot spy the wait property because it is not a function; undefined given instead